# Memory leak in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, memory-leaks

My memory is running full. Can you identify this driver for me? The tag is `MINI`:

[image]

These hieroglyphs in CMD are coming from

```
findstr /s MINI *.sys
```

[image]

System:

1. Windows 8.1 (just reinstalled)
2. 12 GB RAM DDR3
3. Radeon 6950 HD
4. Intel i7 750
5. Vertex 3 as system drive

Comment: Guten Abend. We only communicate in English here, so I took the liberty of translating your post. If you have info to add, please [edit] your post.

Comment: oh sorry, thx for the translation.  I will ceep it in mind

Answer (score 1):

According to a blog comment on a Microsoft site (Sorry I can't find a more authoritative source) MINI is for AMD GPU drivers. The commenter suggests updating your AMD drivers to the latest edition.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2012/08/30/troubleshooting-pool-leaks-part-2-poolmon.aspx

Comment: thanks, I will try to update and play some BF4. The problem didn´t accour for a week, so it may need some time verify

Comment: @user286332 does it happen when you play BF4? if yes, this is a know bug with the AMD drivers and BF4 and there is no fix for it.

Comment: Since I updated it didn´t happened again, but the last time it didn´t appear for a week. So do you have a link for the bug explanation?

Comment: @user286332 I've been trying to solve this for myself. I run with a Radeon HD6950 and been crying rivers. I've compiled what I've done so far here: http://superuser.com/questions/714146/windows-8-1-non-paged-pool-ati-6950-memory-leak