# Windows 8.1 - Non paged Pool - ATI 6950 Memory Leak

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, amd-radeon, memory-leaks

I've seen a couple of questions regarding this issue, but there hasn't been any responses that has solved my problems so I will ask again and list what I've done to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance for any help or input on this issue.

I've been having some issues since upgrading from Windows 7 64-bit to Windows 8.1 64-bit. Currently after I've been playing some games for a while my Non-Paged Pool gets filled up with 6GB of my 8GB of RAM. I am unable to clear this up unless I reboot my machine.

I've been trying to troubleshoot this for a while now without much success. The only way I know of how to make this happen less frequent is to "underclock" my gfx card through the Graphics Overdrive in AMD Catalyst Control Center.

**What I've tested so far**:

***Uninstall Catalyst Control Center***

- This helps a little, if I don't allow CCC to boot on startup or uninstall it it feels like it takes a longer time for non paged pool to fill up.

***Underclock the GPU***

- So far the best "solution" which isn't at all what I want to do. It makes the game more playable.
- Changed High Performance GPU clock settings from 800MHz to 500MHz. and Memory Clock Settings to 1250MHz instead of 1300MHz.
- This will cost me in game performance how ever and I coul just buy a cheaper card... Not a good solution at all.

***Went through these steps*** - which have been suggested on numerous forums.
http://answers.ea.com/t5/Battlefield-4/Direct-X-Function-error-Solutions-Compilation/td-p/1741229

- Solution 1: Change regional settings to English (United States)

  - Doesn't do anything at all to solve the problem.
- Solution 2: DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET msg pop up, didn't have that. But have shut off Origin In Game.

  - Doesn't do anything at all to solve the problem.
- Solution 3: dbcdedit / set increaseuserva 2500

  - Doesn't do anything at all to solve the problem.
- Solution 4: repaired, reinstall Virtual C++ Redist.

  - Doesn't do anything at all to solve the problem.
- Solution 5: delete PROFSAVE_profile.

  - Guess what, this doesn't do anything at all to solve the problem.

I am aware that from the get go these "Solutions" aren't originally intended to solve this problem. But the link has been posted several times as a solution to the problem. Non of these steps does anything to solve memory leaks and mainly aim to solve problems one experience with DX errors and actual error messages that will help you to trouble shoot correctly.

I have uninstalled both Origin and Battlefield 4.
Cleared the registry of any traces of it with Revo Uninstaller Pro
Cleared again with CCleaner 
Installed everything on a seperate HDD from the OS.

**My setup:**

- OS: Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit (6.3 Build 9600)
- CPU: Intel(R) Core i4-2500K 3.30GHz
- RAM: 8GB
- GPU: AMD Radeon HD 6950
- Main Driver: aticfxi64.dll, Version: 13.251.0.0

For example I play some Battlefield 4 (The game where this problem is most common) and after about 30 minutes to 2 hours of gameplay I experience huge FPS drops and will have to reboot the computer.

The Task Manager will look something like this at the time of reboot.

Win 8.1 Task Manager - BF4 Non-Paged pool

```
 Memory

        8,0 GB DDR3

        Speed:  1600 MHz
        Slots used: 2 of 4
        Form factor:    DIMM
        Hardware reserved:  24,9 MB

        Available   722 MB
        Cached  704 MB
        Committed   9,3/16,0 GB
        Paged pool  189 MB
        Non-paged pool  6,0 GB
        In use     7,3 GB
```

I downloaded poolmon.exe to find out which driver is hogging all the RAM. Turns out it is something called MINI.

The output from Poolmon looks like this:

```
Memory: 8363096K Avail:  712632K  PageFlts: 11903   InRam Krnl:45712K P:114436K

Commit:9451000K Limit:16751704K Peak:11838844K            Pool N:6323024K P:196

System pool information

Tag  Type     Allocs            Frees            Diff       Bytes
MINI Nonp    1749141 (   0)   1551938 (   0)   197203  6359425376 (          0)
CM31 Paged     19699 (   0)      3132 (   0)    16567    76189696 (          0)
ViMm Paged   5300680 (   0)   5286460 (   0)    14220     6114528 (          0)
FMfn Paged    235317 (   0)    225504 (   4)     9813     4039648 (      -1536)
Even Nonp     613421 ( 423)    604080 ( 431)     9341     1201024 (      -1024)
Vad  Nonp     759373 (  42)    751019 (  42)     8354     1202976 (          0)
APL_ Paged      6917 (   0)        22 (   0)     6895      885456 (          0)
VadS Nonp     335934 ( 113)    329206 ( 119)     6728      538240 (       -480)
NtFs Paged    135700 (   0)    129289 (   2)     6411      674384 (       -240)
ViMm Nonp    5411552 (   0)   5405184 (   0)     6368     2839456 (          0)
File Nonp     768669 ( 204)    762502 ( 206)     6167     2061776 (       -672)
VdPN Paged  92225143 (   0)  92219342 (   0)     5801      782768 (          0)
MmSt Paged    525835 (  14)    520625 (  15)     5210    12543328 (      -2064)
PnpZ Paged     11042 (   0)      6107 (   0)     4935      778528 (          0)
```

**::EDIT::**

Software information from CCC:

```
Driver Packaging Version    13.35.1005-140131a-167669E-ATI
Catalyst Version    14.1
Provider    Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
2D Driver Version   8.01.01.1379
2D Driver File Path /REGISTRY/MACHINE/SYSTEM/ControlSet001/Control/Class/{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}/0000
Direct3D Version    9.14.10.01017
OpenGL Version  6.14.10.12780
AMD Catalyst Control Center Version 2014.0131.1535.27922
```

**DxDiag**

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
Time of this report: 2/9/2014, 15:13:05
       Machine name: DUXCK-PC
   Operating System: Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit (6.3, Build 9600) (9600.winblue_gdr.131030-1505)
           Language: Swedish (Regional Setting: Swedish)
System Manufacturer: System manufacturer
       System Model: System Product Name
               BIOS: 0402
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500K CPU @ 3.30GHz (4 CPUs), ~3.3GHz
             Memory: 8192MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 8168MB RAM
          Page File: 8504MB used, 7854MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.03.9600.16384 64bit Unicode

------------
DxDiag Notes
------------
      Display Tab 1: The file aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx32,aticfx32,aticfx32,atiumd64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atiumdag,atidxx32,atidxx32,atiumdva,atiumd6a.cap,atitmm64.dll is not digitally signed, which means that it has not been tested by Microsoft's Windows Hardware Quality Labs (WHQL).  You may be able to get a WHQL logo'd driver from the hardware manufacturer.
      Display Tab 2: The file aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx32,aticfx32,aticfx32,atiumd64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atiumdag,atidxx32,atidxx32,atiumdva,atiumd6a.cap,atitmm64.dll is not digitally signed, which means that it has not been tested by Microsoft's Windows Hardware Quality Labs (WHQL).  You may be able to get a WHQL logo'd driver from the hardware manufacturer.
      Display Tab 3: The file aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx32,aticfx32,aticfx32,atiumd64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atiumdag,atidxx32,atidxx32,atiumdva,atiumd6a.cap,atitmm64.dll is not digitally signed, which means that it has not been tested by Microsoft's Windows Hardware Quality Labs (WHQL).  You may be able to get a WHQL logo'd driver from the hardware manufacturer.
        Sound Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 2: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 3: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 4: No problems found.
          Input Tab: No problems found.

--------------------
DirectX Debug Levels
--------------------
Direct3D:    0/4 (retail)
DirectDraw:  0/4 (retail)
DirectInput: 0/5 (retail)
DirectMusic: 0/5 (retail)
DirectPlay:  0/9 (retail)
DirectSound: 0/5 (retail)
DirectShow:  0/6 (retail)

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
          Card name: AMD Radeon HD 6900 Series
       Manufacturer: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
          Chip type: AMD Radeon Graphics Processor (0x6719)
           DAC type: Internal DAC(400MHz)
        Device Type: Full Device
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_6719&SUBSYS_31211682&REV_00
     Display Memory: 5875 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 2035 MB
      Shared Memory: 3840 MB
       Current Mode: 1920 x 1080 (32 bit) (60Hz)
       Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
      Monitor Model: 246EL2SBH
         Monitor Id: PHLC074
        Native Mode: 1920 x 1080(p) (60.000Hz)
        Output Type: Displayport External
        Driver Name: aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx32,aticfx32,aticfx32,atiumd64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atiumdag,atidxx32,atidxx32,atiumdva,atiumd6a.cap,atitmm64.dll
Driver File Version: 8.17.0010.1267 (English)
     Driver Version: 13.350.1005.0
        DDI Version: 11
     Feature Levels: 11.0,10.1,10.0,9.3,9.2,9.1
       Driver Model: WDDM 1.3
Graphics Preemption: DMA
 Compute Preemption: DMA
           Miracast: Not Supported
Hybrid Graphics GPU: Not Supported
     Power P-states: Not Supported
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: 1/31/2014 22:07:22, 1328328 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: No
    WHQL Date Stamp: None
  Device Identifier: {D7B71EE2-2459-11CF-C171-2B11BEC2C535}
          Vendor ID: 0x1002
          Device ID: 0x6719
          SubSys ID: 0x31211682
        Revision ID: 0x0000
 Driver Strong Name: oem36.inf:cb0ae4140e401586:ati2mtag_NICayman:13.350.1005.0:pci\ven_1002&dev_6719
     Rank Of Driver: 00DA2001
        Video Accel: ModeMPEG2_A ModeMPEG2_C 
        DXVA2 Modes: DXVA2_ModeMPEG2_VLD  DXVA2_ModeMPEG2_IDCT  DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_NoFGT  DXVA2_ModeVC1_VLD  
   Deinterlace Caps: {6E8329FF-B642-418B-BCF0-BCB6591E255F}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY 
                     {6E8329FF-B642-418B-BCF0-BCB6591E255F}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,UYVY) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,UYVY) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,UYVY) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(YV12,0x32315659) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {3C5323C1-6FB7-44F5-9081-056BF2EE449D}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,2) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
                     {552C0DAD-CCBC-420B-83C8-74943CF9F1A6}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,2) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
                     {6E8329FF-B642-418B-BCF0-BCB6591E255F}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC1,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC2,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC3,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC4,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(S340,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(S342,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
       D3D9 Overlay: Not Supported
            DXVA-HD: Not Supported
       DDraw Status: Enabled
         D3D Status: Enabled
         AGP Status: Enabled

          Card name: AMD Radeon HD 6900 Series
       Manufacturer: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
          Chip type: AMD Radeon Graphics Processor (0x6719)
           DAC type: Internal DAC(400MHz)
        Device Type: Full Device
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_6719&SUBSYS_31211682&REV_00
     Display Memory: 5875 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 2035 MB
      Shared Memory: 3840 MB
       Current Mode: 1920 x 1080 (32 bit) (60Hz)
       Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
      Monitor Model: 246EL2SBH
         Monitor Id: PHLC074
        Native Mode: 1920 x 1080(p) (60.000Hz)
        Output Type: HDMI
        Driver Name: aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx32,aticfx32,aticfx32,atiumd64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atiumdag,atidxx32,atidxx32,atiumdva,atiumd6a.cap,atitmm64.dll
Driver File Version: 8.17.0010.1267 (English)
     Driver Version: 13.350.1005.0
        DDI Version: 11
     Feature Levels: 11.0,10.1,10.0,9.3,9.2,9.1
       Driver Model: WDDM 1.3
Graphics Preemption: DMA
 Compute Preemption: DMA
           Miracast: Not Supported
Hybrid Graphics GPU: Not Supported
     Power P-states: Not Supported
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: 1/31/2014 22:07:22, 1328328 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: No
    WHQL Date Stamp: None
  Device Identifier: {D7B71EE2-2459-11CF-C171-2B11BEC2C535}
          Vendor ID: 0x1002
          Device ID: 0x6719
          SubSys ID: 0x31211682
        Revision ID: 0x0000
 Driver Strong Name: oem36.inf:cb0ae4140e401586:ati2mtag_NICayman:13.350.1005.0:pci\ven_1002&dev_6719
     Rank Of Driver: 00DA2001
        Video Accel: ModeMPEG2_A ModeMPEG2_C 
        DXVA2 Modes: DXVA2_ModeMPEG2_VLD  DXVA2_ModeMPEG2_IDCT  DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_NoFGT  DXVA2_ModeVC1_VLD  
   Deinterlace Caps: {6E8329FF-B642-418B-BCF0-BCB6591E255F}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY 
                     {6E8329FF-B642-418B-BCF0-BCB6591E255F}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,UYVY) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,UYVY) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,UYVY) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(YV12,0x32315659) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {3C5323C1-6FB7-44F5-9081-056BF2EE449D}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,2) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
                     {552C0DAD-CCBC-420B-83C8-74943CF9F1A6}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,2) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
                     {6E8329FF-B642-418B-BCF0-BCB6591E255F}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC1,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC2,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC3,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC4,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(S340,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(S342,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
       D3D9 Overlay: Not Supported
            DXVA-HD: Not Supported
       DDraw Status: Enabled
         D3D Status: Enabled
         AGP Status: Enabled

          Card name: AMD Radeon HD 6900 Series
       Manufacturer: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
          Chip type: AMD Radeon Graphics Processor (0x6719)
           DAC type: Internal DAC(400MHz)
        Device Type: Full Device
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_6719&SUBSYS_31211682&REV_00
     Display Memory: 5875 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 2035 MB
      Shared Memory: 3840 MB
       Current Mode: 1920 x 1080 (32 bit) (60Hz)
       Monitor Name: BenQ GL2450H
      Monitor Model: BenQ GL2450H
         Monitor Id: BNQ78A7
        Native Mode: 1920 x 1080(p) (60.000Hz)
        Output Type: DVI
        Driver Name: aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx32,aticfx32,aticfx32,atiumd64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atiumdag,atidxx32,atidxx32,atiumdva,atiumd6a.cap,atitmm64.dll
Driver File Version: 8.17.0010.1267 (English)
     Driver Version: 13.350.1005.0
        DDI Version: 11
     Feature Levels: 11.0,10.1,10.0,9.3,9.2,9.1
       Driver Model: WDDM 1.3
Graphics Preemption: DMA
 Compute Preemption: DMA
           Miracast: Not Supported
Hybrid Graphics GPU: Not Supported
     Power P-states: Not Supported
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: 1/31/2014 22:07:22, 1328328 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: No
    WHQL Date Stamp: None
  Device Identifier: {D7B71EE2-2459-11CF-C171-2B11BEC2C535}
          Vendor ID: 0x1002
          Device ID: 0x6719
          SubSys ID: 0x31211682
        Revision ID: 0x0000
 Driver Strong Name: oem36.inf:cb0ae4140e401586:ati2mtag_NICayman:13.350.1005.0:pci\ven_1002&dev_6719
     Rank Of Driver: 00DA2001
        Video Accel: ModeMPEG2_A ModeMPEG2_C 
        DXVA2 Modes: DXVA2_ModeMPEG2_VLD  DXVA2_ModeMPEG2_IDCT  DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_NoFGT  DXVA2_ModeVC1_VLD  
   Deinterlace Caps: {6E8329FF-B642-418B-BCF0-BCB6591E255F}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(YUY2,YUY2) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY 
                     {6E8329FF-B642-418B-BCF0-BCB6591E255F}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,UYVY) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,UYVY) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(UYVY,UYVY) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(YV12,0x32315659) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {3C5323C1-6FB7-44F5-9081-056BF2EE449D}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,2) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
                     {552C0DAD-CCBC-420B-83C8-74943CF9F1A6}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,2) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
                     {6E8329FF-B642-418B-BCF0-BCB6591E255F}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,1) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_PixelAdaptive 
                     {335AA36E-7884-43A4-9C91-7F87FAF3E37E}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY DeinterlaceTech_BOBVerticalStretch 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(NV12,0x3231564e) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=VideoProcess_YUV2RGB VideoProcess_StretchX VideoProcess_StretchY 
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC1,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC2,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC3,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(IMC4,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(S340,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
                     {5A54A0C9-C7EC-4BD9-8EDE-F3C75DC4393B}: Format(In/Out)=(S342,UNKNOWN) Frames(Prev/Fwd/Back)=(0,0,0) Caps=
       D3D9 Overlay: Not Supported
            DXVA-HD: Not Supported
       DDraw Status: Enabled
         D3D Status: Enabled
         AGP Status: Enabled
```

Comment: Two pieces of information that would be nice to have is the version of the AMD driver your using and a dxdiag report.  Please reference the driver version by the version of the CCC that has been released.

Comment: @Ramhound I have now edited the original post with that information.

Comment: have you tried the 14.1 beta driver? http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-catalyst-windows-beta.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 No I have not. That wasn't out last time I checked. I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have no tested out with the latest drivers, and both the 32-bit and 64-bit version of the BF4 client. Still the same problem.

Comment: in this case contact DICE and AMD so that they can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've sorted this for myself now. It is not a solution but more of a fix. 
I've noticed that if I run BF4.exe in compatibility mode with Windows 8 I don't get these memory leaks.

So if you're experiencing this as well, try the following.

1. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Battlefield 4`
2. Right click BF4.exe (or BF4_x85.exe of you run it in 32-bit)
3. Select the Compatibility menu
4. Check "Run this program in compatibility mode for: " and Select Windows 8.

Press OK and try it out.
Hope that this sorts it for some people as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same videocard and also experience this memory leak.
The only thing that seems to help is to disable the overlays.
After disabling the overlay from AMD Gaming Evolved and the one in Origin the problem hasnt presented itself yet.
I also set the compatibility like duxck says, but with the overlays still turned on i still got the leak.